# How should the favorites be organized in the breadcrumbs section?

Tags: usability, breadcrumbs

During development of our application we found a problem related to breadcrumbs. We are not sure of two things.

The first is what should go up where the question makrs are located. Both tables are important and user should know where they are in the application.

The second is related to adding favorites. If the user wants to favorite the tables, how should that be approached? Is it best practice to add each of them or just the whole page?

[image: where should be favorites icons and what inside breadcrumbs]

Comment: Just for clarification: groups 1 and 2 are separate, but both belong to group 0?

Comment: @BDD +1 for perfect editing!

Comment: @AlanGeorge yes

Answer (score 2):

- **Breadcrumbs** are used to show the **location** of the user in the site hierarchy. It is always a **secondary navigation** for moving in a site. 
  The current location shown by breadcrumbs are relative to the high level concepts helping users know where they are in relation to the site.

In your case, the two tables are part of Group 0 of the page. The breadcrumb hence must indicate the user "Group 0" which gives fairly good idea about their location in the site. It shows site hierarchy and not users history. 
Specifying details further, like Group 1 or Group 2 is unnecessary and it will complicate the design and the very purpose of the breadcrumb.

Having said that, the use of your breadcrumb must be consistent all through out the site in this way.

Hence, coming to the second part of the question, the favorites should contain the page where Group 0. That is **whole page**. A common use case is, adding a "**Page**" to Favorites, and not the sections of the page to favorites.

Comment: I't totally agree but if I have details on the table and do smth inside. Example: after clicking on the table row form with detailed view of item opens. And I want to save page in that view as a favorite. Than the breadcrumb should be like Group0>Group1>Selected item?